# how to make int values in R.java into String

Tags: android, eclipse, string, arraylist, integer

I am working on a project with a spinner and `ArrayList` and I want to use left to right language (Persian)
this is my code:

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerVolume1);
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("*****");
```

I want to use Persian words as ***** but eclipse doesnt let me.
I tried using String in res/values like this:
res/values/strings.xml ==>>      سلام
and tried this one:

```
list1.add(R.String.hello);
```

but in code, Eclipse tells me to turn hello to String.

Also tried this code:

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerVolume1);
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(R.String.hello);
```

but when I ran the app, I saw number (2131099648) instead of سلام

Comment: Do it like this 

list1.add(mContext.getResources().getString(R.String.hello));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getString()`:

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerVolume1);
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(getString(R.String.hello));
```

> **public final String getString (int resId)** 
>   Return a localized string from the application's package's default string table.

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)

Comment: worked well, one more question plz. what if I had 
<string-array name="hello">سلام</string-array> in res/value/strings

Comment: You should use `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hello)`. You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)